# object value styling in Vue3 composition api

Tags: css, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

- I have 3 checkboxes and a infoBox if none of the checkboxes are selected i want to display a default message if one of the checkbox is selected i want to display a message related to that checkbox if more than one checkbox is selected again i want to display a default message.
- I have params object and it contains my array of infoTypes which contains the values of selected checkboxes. I tried to code it like below but couldn't do what i want.
- what i am trying to do is to apply css to my infoBodyOptions objects values. For instance i want to make 'This is a DESCRIPTION Message Body' text or i just want to make 'DESCRIPTION' bolder in that text

```
<template>
  <div class="content-quality__wrapper-info">
    <SomeRandomComponent1 />
    <SomeRandomComponent2 />
    <div class="content-quality__info">
      <h1 class="content-quality__info--title">{{infoTitleOptions[selected]}}</h1>
      <p class="content-quality__info--text">{{infoBodyOptions[selected]}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import SomeRandomComponent1 from "../components/SomeRandomComponent1.vue";
import SomeRandomComponent2 from "../components/SomeRandomComponent2.vue";
import { useListContext } from "../composables/useListContext.js";
import { computed } from "vue";

const { params } = useListContext();

const selected = computed(() => {
  if (params.value.infoTypes.length === 1) {
    return params.value.infoTypes[0];
  } else {
    return "DEFAULT";
  }
})

const infoTitleOptions = {
  DEFAULT: 'This is a Default Message Title',
  VIDEO: 'This is a VIDEO Message Title',
  IMAGE: 'This is a IMAGE Message Title',
  DESCRIPTION: 'This is a DESCRIPTION Message Title',
}

const infoBodyOptions = {
  DEFAULT: 'This is a Default Message Body',
  VIDEO: 'This is a VIDEO Message Body',
  IMAGE: 'This is a IMAGE Message Body',
  DESCRIPTION: 'This is a DESCRIPTION Message Body',
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content-quality {
  &__wrapper-info {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    display: flex;
  }
  &__info {
    background: #f7f7fa;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    &--title {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #273142;
    }
    &--text {
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #273142;
        margin-top: 0.25rem;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

```
const infoBodyOptions = {
  DEFAULT: 'This is a Default Message Body',
  VIDEO: 'This is a VIDEO Message Body',
  IMAGE: '<span>This is a IMAGE Message Body</span>',
  DESCRIPTION: 'This is a <strong>DESCRIPTION</strong> Message Body',
}
```

i tried some tags for it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-html` to insert your text as HTML:

```
<h1 class="content-quality__info--title" v-html="infoTitleOptions[selected]"></h1>
<p class="content-quality__info--text" v-html="infoBodyOptions[selected]"></p>
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html